# Streaming audio files over HTTP with Media Player Daemon fails - 'Not found'

Tags: audio, http, mpd

I'm trying to set up a simple MPD instance to stream audio files over HTTP. What I'd like to be able to do is put in a URL in my browser, which will stream the audio file - as simple as possible.

I've set MPD to listen to a local port, and it appears to be working - I get an `OK MPD 0.23.4` when browsing to `[my-IP]:6600`.
I've tried setting the built in HTTPD server as well:

```
audio_output {
        type            "httpd"
        name            "HTTP Stream"
        encoder "vorbis"                # optional, vorbis or lame
        port            "8000"
        bind_to_address "[my-ip]"          # optional, IPv4 or IPv6
##      quality         "6.0"                   # do not define if bitrate is defined
        bitrate         "192"                   # do not define if quality is defined
        format          "48000:16:2"
        max_clients     "0"                     # optional 0=no limit
}
```

Once that was done, I added a file named `test.ogg` to the top level directory - and MPD picks it up (from  `/var/log/mpd.log`):

`update: added /test.ogg`

But when trying to access the file via browser or VLC (`[my-ip]:8000/test.ogg`) , I get an error:

`Not found`

MPD runs from my user, and permissions are OK - I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

How can I get MPD to stream HTTP files, as simply as possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MPD does not stream the audio with the file path, only on predefined paths, e.g. `[my-ip]:8000/` or `[my-ip]:8000/mpd.mp3`.